# Save data to custom field from youtube api

Tags: wordpress, api, youtube, custom-post-type, custom-fields

I've made a wordpress video section for one of my clients. In the backend it's a custom post type where the users can place the ID (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=**kFHshctPO9E**) of a video.

With this **ID** i embed the video and get the **duration** and **rating** of each video from the youtube api.

Now each time a video is loaded (in the overview template all the video's are loaded) it has to reach out to YouTube to get the duration (which i then parse to hours and minutes instead of seconds) and rating of all video's.

I would somehow like to cache or save these values to a custom field or somewhat.

Anyone got any idea?

Thank in advance!

Rick

Answer (score 1):

You can use `post_meta` to save this information the first time the post is saved and then load the information from the database instead of using youtube api again.

I put you an example in pseudocode:

```
add_action('save_post', 'my_function_to_save_posts_action');
function my_function_to_save_posts_action($post_id) {
  $the_post = get_post($post_id);
  if ($the_post->type == 'my_custom_post_type') {
    $youtube_data = my_function_to_retrieve_youtube_data();
    if (my_function_exists_post_meta($post_id)) {
      update_post_meta($post_id, 'my_video_duration', $youtube_data['duration']);
      update_post_meta($post_id, 'my_video_rating', $youtube_data['rating']);
    }
    else {
      add_post_meta($post_id, 'my_video_duration', $youtube_data['duration'], true);
      add_post_meta($post_id, 'my_video_rating', $youtube_data['rating'], true);
    }
  }
}
```

And of course, when you are queryng for your custom post type you must retrive the post_meta information and show this information properly.